# SMO package on IIS impossible?

Tags: smo

I have a dev using entity framework trying to deploy a website to IIS via VS2022 using WebDeploy.  When that dev deploys it fails and server side events shows error ERROR_SMO_NEEDED_FOR_SQL_PROVIDER.

Now according to [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/server-management-objects-smo/installing-smo?view=sql-server-ver16) this Microsoft.SqlServer.SqlManagementObjects package is now a NuGet package...

When I try to install, package cannot be found. NuGet repo not present on Windows Server...
I install NuGet (only 2.8.5 available for some reason). The package is now found but fails due to dependency loop:

```
PS> Find-PackageProvider -Name NuGet | Install-PackageProvider -Force
PS> Install-Package Microsoft.SqlServer.SqlManagementObjects -Verbose

Install-Package : Dependency loop detected for package 'Microsoft.SqlServer.SqlManagementObjects'.
At line:1 char:1
+ Install-Package Microsoft.SqlServer.SqlManagementObjects -Verbose
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : Deadlock detected: (Microsoft.SqlServer.SqlManagementObjects:String) [Install-Package], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DependencyLoopDetected,Microsoft.PowerShell.PackageManagement.Cmdlets.InstallPackage
```

This all works on my machine or in dev's Visual Studio.
All [documentation](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.SqlServer.SqlManagementObjects) show how to install on client machines rather than on Server/IIS.

So, how would one install SMO on server 2019? Or is it not meant to be done and dev needs to adjust something on his side?

Target server is running IIS 10 on Win2019. Database is SQL2022 running on a different server.